# Shrink Database Log file for Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, sql-server-2014, logfile

I have Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 and the database file (.mdf) is around 20 Gb and the Log file (.ldf) is about 550 Gb. I tried shrinking ldf file as discussed in [this link](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e1cc94a-750b-4c72-8b98-3a8a066bd18e/cleaning-up-crm-ldf-database?forum=crm)

However, after the database log file was shrink, CRM stopped working. Can anyone advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CRM stopped working

What error messages do your receive?

Just based on my assumptions:

Obviously that database is not in a SIMPLE recovery mode and no scheduled backup of the transaction log configured.

1. First of all, make sense to check why you cannot shrink the log:

> ```
> SELECT
>     name,
>     log_reuse_wait_desc,
>     recovery_model_desc
>     FROM sys.databases
> WHERE name = 'yourDB'
> ```

2. Then, you may set the database to a SIMPLE recovery:

> `ALTER DATABASE [yourDB] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE`

OR, fix your backup of transaction log if, this is a reason

3. then you have to shrink the log:

> `USE [yourDB] 
>   DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 256)`

When your database back to the operational state you have to decide what kind of backup scheme do you want yo have:

- Full/diff backups per day every night
- Full/diffs overnigt and Transactional backups every n minutes.

Depends on a choice, you will have to stay with SIMPLE recovery or switch back to FULL, but add missing scheduled backups of your transaction log